# Unrecognized Selector sent to instance, not view related

Tags: ios, swift

I have an annoying problem in my iOS app. Suddenly, when I start my view controller with a table view inside, I get the following error:

> Unrecognized selector sent to instance

After googling a lot about this problem, it seems like it is usually related to a falsely connected IBOutlet/IBAction or generally something with the UI.

But I could exclude these causes, since I removed all IBOutlets and the problem still persisted.

After long hours, I found the solution for this and wanted to share it in a Q&A fashion, in case someone else is having a hard time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line of code:

```
outletCommentShowMore.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
   string: isExpanded ? "show less" : "show more", 
   attributes: [
       NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : Theme.primaryTextColor,
       NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle
   ]
)
```

The error was that I passed an enum (`NSUnderline.styleSingle`) directly into the attributes dictionary of an NSAttributedString. But it has to be the rawValue of the enum!
So after changing this to `NSUnderline.styleSingle.rawValue` my error disappeared

Hope this helps someone